# list file names from a remote server directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I want to list the files recursively in a remote directory and its subdirectories as well. I know can do this by calling the listFiles method of ListGateway as:

> List list = listGateway.listFiles("/ussama/providers")

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface ListGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "listSftpChannel")
    List<File> listFiles(String dir);

}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "listSftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "ls", "'/directory'");
    return  sftpOutboundGateway;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpOutboundListFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("listSftpChannel")
            .handle(new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "ls", "payload")
            ).get();
}
```

But I want to do it after every x minutes. Is there a way i can poll the remote directory to list files after every x minutes. Plz give java configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poll a simple POJO message source for the directory and configure the poller as needed...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pollLs(SessionFactory<LsEntry> sessionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "foo/bar", e -> e
                .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(sessionFactory, Command.LS, "payload")
                    .options(Option.RECURSIVE))
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
}
```

Obviously you will need some service in the `.handle` to receive the `List<LsEntry>` result.

By the way, there is a factory class `Sftp` with convenient methods for creating endpoints.

Comment: thanks gary, can you plz tell me how can i make this ls command to return list of only newly created/modified files or the files created/modified after a given timestamp?

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) `>In addition, filename filtering is provided in the same manner as the inbound-channel-adapter.`. Use an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` with some metadata store to persist the file information.